# Sobre o mecanismo de fechamento de perguntas

Tags: suporte, fechamento, experiência

Eu gostaria de saber a motivação por trás do mecanismo de fechamento de perguntas que impede que se vote para fechar uma pergunta após um voto já ter sido dado e retirado no passado.

Não que isso me incomode (muito), mas há algum motivo sistêmico ou comportamental relacionado à essa função?

A alternativa, isto é, se essa função não existisse, seria que qualquer usuário poderia simplesmente alterar seu tipo de voto ou mesmo mudar de ideia sobre votar ou não pra fechar sem pressão de "voto único" (algo as vezes necessário com usuários novatos relativamente teimosos).

Comment: Vou ver se acho alguma coisa respondida no metão, mas minha resposta não seria a mais autoritativa. Me lembro alguma coisa que havia uma ideia de que você deve votar com certeza, por isso não pode votar de novo. Há problemas óbvios nessa ideia, já que o problema da pergunta pode mudar.

Comment: @bigown era fixe uma boa explicação sobre o assunto. Não sei se não há qualquer coisa aqui no meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O motivo por trás disso vem de um tempo em que *guerras de fechamento* eram comuns no Stack Overflow, e algumas pessoas aproveitavam qualquer oportunidade parar garantir que "seu lado" vencesse a batalha. O sistema de fechamento foi modificado diversas vezes ao longo dos anos, mas sem dúvida a alteração mais eficaz foi também a mais simples: **uma pessoa, uma pergunta, um voto**.

Essa regra, apesar de simples, tem efeitos bem fortes:

- Te impede de botar a mesma pergunta na fila de revisão repetidas vezes, até que apareçam 4 revisores que concordem com você
- Te impede de ficar escolhendo novos motivos de fechamento constantemente, quando os problemas anteriores são resolvidos
- Te impede de *mascarar* seu envolvimento, fingindo ser apenas o último voto quando na verdade você foi o primeiro (sim, várias pessoas já tentarem isso, de várias maneiras).

Em resumo, mantém a honestidade do processo. Apesar de existirem casos específicos em que seria bom poder *alterar* um voto de fechamento, esses casos são raros e facilmente tratados por outros caminhos (e, às vezes, sequer precisam ser tratados).

É bom ressaltar que existe *uma* exceção à essa regra: se o seu voto *expirar*, então você pode votar novamente depois de 14 dias. Isso é permitido para ajudar os que participam de áreas menos movimentadas do site, onde perguntas podem demorar mais tempo para atrair usuários suficientes com privilégios de voto ou revisão, para que ela seja fechada à tempo.

Comment: É assustador saber que há pessoas dispostas a fazer esse tipo de coisa. :/ Obrigado pela resposta! (*It is terrifying to know that there are people willing to do that sort of thing. :/ Tks for the reply!*)

Comment: Inacreditável mesmo que tenha gente disposta a fazer este tipo de uso do site.

Comment: Então acredito que isso ainda seja uma pratica existente, pois vejo algumas pessoas fazendo perguntas de forma correta e outras fechando como se não conseguisse responder então fecha.