# Podemos votar mais de uma vez para fechar uma pergunta?

Tags: suporte, fechamento, votos

Hoje, ao tentar votar no fechamento de uma pergunta que eu já tinha votado anteriormente deparei-me com a mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde podemos ver duas coisas interessantes:

1. O botão de remover o voto sumiu;
2. O texto diz "[...] você pode atribuir seu voto **novamente** [...]"

Foi alguma mudança recente? Não podemos mais retirar o voto? Iremos, depois de um tempo, votar novamente pelo fechamento da pergunta? Se sim, como funcionará isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Os votos de fechamento expiram após um determinado tempo, caso a pergunta não seja fechada. E nesse caso você tem a opção de votar novamente na mesma pergunta.

A regra exata, conforme a [central de ajuda do MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), seria:

> Close votes age away harmlessly if the threshold is not reach after a number of days. If the question has at least 100 views, close votes will age away after 4 days; otherwise close votes will age away after 14 days. Each new close vote resets the timer, so all close votes must be at least 4 or 14 days old respectively before aging occurs.

Tradução:

> Votos de fechamento expiram caso certos limites não sejam atingido após determinado tempo. Se a pergunta tiver pelo menos 100 visualizações, os votos expiram após 4 dias; caso tenham menos visualizações, expiram após 14 dias. Cada novo voto de fechamento zera o contador, então todos os votos precisam ter no mínimo 4 ou 14 dias antes que possam expirar.

(Acho que [a nossa versão desse texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) está desatualizada, pois menciona a regra anterior a [2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting).

E isso foi [implementado junto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting) com essa restrição:

> Allow re-casting votes that've aged away after 14 days. That is, 14 days (use the same site-configurable value used in #1 here) after your vote has aged away, you're free to cast the same vote again.

Tradução:

> Permitir votar novamente para fechar, 14 dias após o seu voto de fechamento anterior ter expirado.

Por outro lado, se tiver votado e removido seu voto, não é possível votar novamente na pergunta, conforme explicado em [Sobre o mecanismo de fechamento de perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5270/sobre-o-mecanismo-de-fechamento-de-perguntas/5275#5275). Só não tenho certeza se a expiração dos demais votos de fechamento zeraria esse caso também.